# How can I set different permissions for files and folders separately?

Tags: 12.04, permissions, 14.04, chmod

I want to apply `644` permissions only for all files in current directory, and `755` permissions only for subdirectories in current directory with `chmod`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `find`:

```
find ./ -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find ./ -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

- `-type f`: Files
- `-type d`: Directories
- `-maxdepth 1`: first level (to avoid default recursive behavior)
- `-exec`: execute command on with argument from result
- `{}` will be replaced with a line from results. try:

  ```
  find ./ -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec echo hi{}low \;
  ```

  This useful for commands which have different arguments order like `ln`:

  ```
  ln -s {} ./otherfolder/{}
  ```

  or `cp`

  ```
  cp {} ./otherfolder/
  ```
- `\;` to to tell `-exec` is the end of command because you can add other `find` options after `-exec` (so they will not mix up). try:

  ```
  find ./ -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec echo
  ```

Reference: [`man find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/find.1.html)

Comment: What is mean `{} \;`? It's really necessary?

Comment: @brainforce. yep, `{}` will be replaced with a line from results and `\;` to to tell `-exec` is the end of command because you can add other `find` options after `-exec`. try `find ./ -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec echo`  and this  `find ./ -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec echo hi{}low \;`

Comment: For me, `find` warns about putting `-maxdepth` after other arguments. To silence the warning, do `find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;` instead.