# How to set permisson back to Read-only via ssh?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

with following command i set up a permission and can edit and change file online:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /home/admin/web/
```

How can i rmeove this permission so that i can only read files form online, Wordpress?

Comment: Generally `644` is recommended for the PHP files and `755` for the directory (and files) containing uploaded assets such as images and audio.

Comment: ... you may find this helpful to restore sensible permissions: [How can I set different permissions for files and folders separately?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463299/how-can-i-set-different-permissions-for-files-and-folders-separately)

Answer (score 0):

The `chmod` command has an easy to remember way of setting permissions. Instead of the numeric code, you can use letters `r w x` to add (+) or remove (-) **r**ead, **w**rite and e**x**ecute permissions (navigate in case of directories). In addition, you can use `u g o a` to select which user is affected by the change (current **u**ser, current **g**roup, **a**ll users...)

There's more info about this and more options in the man page at `$ man chmod`

The command to set the file back from `777` to read only for **a**ll users would be:

`$ sudo chmod a-rw /home/admin/web`

You can see the permissions are set to read-only in the first column of `$ ls -l` output:

```
$ ls -l
···
-r--r--r-- 1 user group  968 Mar  6 21:59 web
···
$
```